# strcmp returning only 0 (palindrom algo bug)

Tags: c, strcmp, string.h

Hi I learned in class about the string.h library and specifically about the strcmp function that compares between to strings .
and if the first string appears first in the dictionary it will return a number bigger than 0 , if the second string is bigger than first than it will return a number smaller than 0 , and if they are equil its supposed to return a 0.
ive used it like this :

```
strcmp(strArr , strrev(strArr));
```

Feel free to educate me.

The code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100
#define PALINDROM_TRUE 0//because in strcmp if both strings compared are equile the strcmp will return 0.
int main(void)
{
    char strArr[MAX_LENGTH];
    printf("Enter string (max length 100 chars): ");
    fgets(strArr , MAX_LENGTH , stdin);
    int pali = strcmp(strArr , strrev(strArr));
    if(pali == PALINDROM_TRUE)
    {
        printf("Palindrom\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not Palindrom\n");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

my problem is that the code below when I enter i.e "abc" it prints to the screen *Palindrom* which it should print *Not Palindrom* , it never prints *Not Palindrom*

Comment: Have you tried printing out the values of `strArr` and `strrev(strArr)` to make sure they have the values you expect?

Comment: damn ive managed to make pali an 'int' , sorry for this.

Comment: Your "*fix*" for the way `strcmp()` works is a potential confusion source. Instead, try something like `#define strequal(x, y) (strcmp((x), (y)) == 0)` and then `if (strequal(x, y) == true)` ...

Comment: this line: `#define PALINDROM_TRUE 0//because in strcmp if both strings compared are equile the strcmp will return 0.`  will include the comment where ever the macro: `PALINDROM_TRUE` is used.  That means the rest of the line where that macro is used will ALL be treated as a comment.  Strongly suggest placing the comment on a separate line

Comment: the posted code is missing a couple lines following the call to `fgets()` to remove any (possible) newline char sequence from the string.

Comment: this line: `system("PAUSE");` is not portable (it is specific to windows/DOS OS)  so will not work for other OSs, like linux

Comment: this line: `if(pali == PALINDROM_TRUE)` would be much better written as: `if( !pali )`  which would allow the elimination of the macro: `PALINDROM_TRUE`

Comment: the posted code will only allow the user to enter 99 characters, not 100, as the function: `fgets()` will always stop at (in this scenario) 99 characters, so there is room to insert the trailing NUL character.

Comment: one way to remove a possible trailing newline:  `char *newline = NULL; if( NULL != (newline = strchr( strArr, '\n' )) ) { *newline = '\0'; }

Comment: strongly suggest reading/understanding the `man` page for `strrev()` One important detail on that man page:  the function makes the modifications 'inplace', so the original string is lost.   suggest adding a line: char *copy = strdup(strArr);`  then making the comparison as: `poli = strcmp( strrev(copy), strArr );`  of course, check that `copy` is not NULL to assure the call to `strdup()` was successful, then at the end add a call to `free(copy);`

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this is your call to strrev(). strrev() function works in-place. In other words, strrev works on the same buffer(i.e. strArr array) as the original array, and does not allocate a new space for the reversed string. As a result, once you call strrev() with strArr, the string in strArr is reversed, and all you are doing is comparing the two identical strings: the one in strArr, and again, the one in strArr, both of which are now reversed. (Note that the term both may be misguiding. Actually, there is just a single buffer and both arguments to strcmp point to that one.)

One way to correct this issue is to allocate a second array strArr2 and copy the string into it. Then, reverse the string in strArr2, and call strcmp with strArr and strArr2. Below is how this solution would look like in code.

```
    ...
    char strArr2[MAX_LENGTH];
    ...
    strcpy(strArr2, strArr);
    strrev(strArr2);
    int pali = strcmp(strArr , strArr2);
    if(pali == PALINDROM_TRUE)
    {
        printf("Palindrom\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not Palindrom\n");
    }
    ...
```

Note that you may also have to check the end of strArr for any trailing whitespace characters, due to your specific method of taking input. Any such trailing whitespace character could render your *reversing and comparing* strategy useless by affecting the result of the comparison.

If you do not have that much space, or if MAX_SPACE is too large a value, another way would be to use a custom comparison function for checking if a string is palindrome without having to use strcmp or strrev.

Comment: @ilim still not working , now it only print _Not Palindrom_. Ive tried to print the two strings and it prints it with 3 lines of spacing between them even though im not using \n at all.

Comment: @ilim anyway to make this code work when a user enters a space??

Comment: @spyc In order to handle input with space character(s), depending on your input specifications, you should either look into the details of the format string of scanf, or try using getchar. That being said, your original question is regarding the workings of strcmp and I you should look into previously asked questions on SO about handling space while taking input.

Answer (score 2):

```
int pali = strcmp(strArr , strrev(strArr));
```

This line is obviously the issue.

The call to `strrev(strArr)` reverses `strArr` so afterwards when `strcmp` is called, do you expect `strArr` to be different? But it's the same variable...

You must create another `char` array to store the reversed string.

**EDIT:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAX_LENGTH];
    char rev[MAX_LENGTH];

    puts("Enter string (max length 100 chars): ");
    scanf("%s", str); 

    strcpy(rev, str);
    strrev(rev);

    if(strcmp(str, rev) == 0) {
        puts("Palindrom"); 
    } else {
        puts("Not Palindrom");
    }
}
```

Comment: like so?                                                                                                       'strcpy(strArrRev , strArr);strrev(strArrRev);int pali = strcmp(strArr , strArrRev);'

Comment: @spyc That looks fine on first glance, yes.

Comment: when compiled with the change , it never shows up as a palindrom , and when I print the two they show up with three lines of space between and as i.e abc cba. but when I do aabbaa it shows up aabbaa and it still writes that its not a pali.

Comment: please not that I was intentionally avoiding scanf , as it as discovered lately to introduce security issues (lets you rewrite memory , out of what was allocated to you) .

Comment: consider writing `scanf("%99s", str);` to avoid the potential buffer overflow, and check the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

ive added

```
strArr[strcspn(strArr, "\n")] = 0;
```

after

```
fgets(strArr , MAX_LENGTH , stdin);
```

And it worked , its basicly rewriting the (null) at the end. which was messing up the reverse to include null (0) at the start of the string.
Thanks everyone.

Finsihed Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100
#define PALINDROM_TRUE 0//because in strcmp if both strings compared are equile the strcmp will return 0.
int main(void)
{
    char strArr[MAX_LENGTH], strArrRev[MAX_LENGTH];
    printf("Enter string (max length 100 chars): ");
    fgets(strArr , MAX_LENGTH , stdin);
    strArr[strcspn(strArr, "\n")] = 0;
    strcpy(strArrRev, strArr);
    int pali = strcmp(strArr , strrev(strArrRev));
    if(pali == PALINDROM_TRUE)
    {
        printf("Palindrom\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not Palindrom\n");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```